# Problemas con Cuadritos al Generar un Documento con Word Interop

Tags: c#, windows10, codificación, ms-word

Estimada comunidad

Estoy manteniendo una aplicación en .Net Frameword 3.5 C# que genera un word (.doc word 2013) con datos de la base de datos, sucede que cuando estos datos son plasmados en el archivo de word queda con caracteres extraños y lo peculiar es que solo sucede en mi maquina.

Tengo estas preguntas que quisiera resolver:

1. Como puedo cambiar la codificación de mi maquina para que esto no me suceda?
2. Si el 1. no es posible que puedo realiza para solventar esta dificultad?

les dejo una imagen del texto en el archivo de word de ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta aplicación trabaja con una plantilla la cual es un archivo con unas leyendas y una Keywords las cuales se utilizan para reemplazarlas por la información.

```
   private bool SearchReplace(string Header, string Data)
    {
        bool Error = false;           
        object format = false;           
        object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;

        if (Data.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string temp = "";
                bool Continuar = true;

                Word.Find findObject = oWord.Selection.Find;

                do
                {
                    temp = Data;

                    if (temp.Length > 255)
                    {
                        temp = temp.Substring(0, (255 - Header.Length)) + Header;
                        Data = Data.Substring(255 - Header.Length);
                    }
                    else
                        Continuar = false;

                    findObject.ClearFormatting();
                    findObject.Text = Header;
                    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                    findObject.Replacement.Text = temp;

                    findObject.Execute(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref format, ref oMissing,
                            ref replaceAll, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

                } while (Continuar);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {

                lstMsgException.Add("SearchReplace Firmas: " + ex.Message.ToString());
                Error = true;
            }
        }
        else
            Error = true;

        return Error;
    }
```

pensé haberlo solucionado con eliminar los `\n` de las concatenaciones pero si de la base de datos me viene los saltos de linea, no tengo como omitirlos y al escribirse en el word me vuelven aparecer estos cuadros.

solicito su amable ayuda con este caso y su amable orientación

gracias

Comment: como estas asignando el texto al word, podrias poner esa parte del codigo ? si pones un breakpoint en ese momento observas que el texto se lee correctamente ?

Comment: Buenas @LeandroTuttini gracias por responder, La respuesta a que si lo leo correctamente es si, el problema creería que va mas asociado a los caracteres  `\n` y `\r` al plasmarse en el word, ya he revisado en 2003 y en esta versión de word no me aparecen estos caracteres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo conseguí, de tanto investigar y intentarlo, estaba concatenando un mensaje de la base de datos y al final para el salto de linea colocaba `\n\r`, decidí cambiarlo por `Environment.NewLine`pero aun me aparecía los cuadritos en el word.

decidí Reemplazar el `\n` y quedo perfecto...!! solo con `\r` y dejarlos con extensión .docx

la razón puntual por que sucede esto aun no la se pero así solvente el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Justamente en este ejemplo no es un problema de codificación según parece, porque lo que no toma el Word son los saltos de lineas. Por mas que incluso lo hagas con [System.Environment.NewLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline). En word se "codifica" de otra manera los saltos de lineas, o sea los [parrafos](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph).

Ademas en tu ejemplo estas utilizando [Word Interop - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.application?view=word-pia) directamente el word instalado en la maquina donde estas ejecutando el código/app, la recomendación seria utilizar [OpenXML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk), así que te dejo la inquietud si lo quieres ver o investigar.

Ejemplo con OpenXml, que lo puedes ver aquí

- [Inserting newlines in Word using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871887/inserting-newlines-in-word-using-openxml)

pero dejo el ejemplo para tenerlo mas rápidamente a la vista

```
run.AppendChild(new Text("The force"));
run.AppendChild(new Break());
run.AppendChild(new Text("is strong in you"));
```

Y será el resultado

```
<w:r>
   <w:t>The force</w:t>
   <w:br/>
   <w:t>is strong in you</w:t>
 </w:r>
```

Pero como en tu proyecto heredado estas utilizando [Word Interop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.application?view=word-pia), deberías ver como ir agregando [parrafos/Paragraph](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph) a medida que parseas el texto y obtienes cada uno (separando por cada \n que encuentres en el texto). Como no he utilizado Word Interop te puede servir estos enlaces

- [How to Create Word Document Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/)
- [How to add items one at a time to to a new line a word document using word interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718044/how-to-add-items-one-at-a-time-to-to-a-new-line-a-word-document-using-word-inter)

Un ejemplo con párrafos

```
var appWord = new Application() { Visible = true };
var document = appWord.Documents.Open(@"..\Starwars.docx", Visible: true);

var p1 = document.Paragraphs.Add();
p1.Range.Text = String.Format("The force");
p1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

var p2 = document.Paragraphs.Add();
p2.Range.Text = String.Format("is strong in you");
p2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

También podría ser de utilidad este método [Range.InsertBreak](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.insertbreak?view=word-pia)
Pero aquí tendrías que ver la enumeración [wdbreaktype](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdbreaktype?view=word-pia) donde podrás ver "wdLineBreak" para insertar en el párrafo un salto de linea. Pero tendrías que buscar como se utiliza.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Esto si me serviría para la versión de Word anteriores al 2010?

Comment: Debería, ya que son elementos básicos de Parrafos y Saltos de linea/pagina. Pero la recomendaciones es utilizar OpenXML.